# Apply a operation to every item in a set in Python

Tags: python-3.x, set

Is there any way of applying a function to every item in a set. For example, i want to make a every item in a set lowercase. If it was a list, i could do this as:

```
 new_list = [item.lower() for item in old_list]
```

Obviously i could convert the set to a list, then do this, and then convert it back to a set again, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
new_set = {set.lower() for item in old_set}
```

This is a set [comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) rather than a list comprehension.