# Is it possible to apply an operation "in place" to every item of a set in Python?

Tags: python, set

I would like to remove a prefix (if present) in a set of unique names.

```
unique_names = {'A_first','A_second','A_third','other'}
```

One way to do this, is to convert the set into a list:

```
unique_names = list(unique_names)

for i, name in enumerate(unique_names):
    if name.startswith('A_'):
        unique_names[i] = name[2:]
```

Another way, could be creating a new set like explained here:
[Apply a operation to every item in a set in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231225/apply-a-operation-to-every-item-in-a-set-in-python)

However both solutions require to create a new object.
Is it possible to do this "in place", without creating a new object?
If not, what is the most efficient way to apply the operation to every item?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: Are you asking about not creating new string objects or not creating a new `set` object? Because the former is not possible.

Comment: Are temporary datastructures that hold strings allowed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity I wanted to know if it was possible to do this without creating a new set object.  And, if not possible, what was the most efficient (or "Pythonic") way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set comprehension too

```py
unique_names = {name[2:] if name.startswith('A_') else name for name in unique_names}
```

Comment: OP wants to mutate the set, not reassign to a new one.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks for the vote down. Btw, OP was asking the most efficient way and said all solutions are allowed ;)

Comment: @user18048269 I've updated the set comprehension to not remove `other` from the set

Comment: As I advertised your answer in mine, I think I should to upvote yours... Because it is indeed the way to go. So +1 ...

Answer (score 4):

You will have 2 problems here:

1. you are not allowed to change a container while iterating it, and a set has no direct accessor (no `__getitem__` method)
2. strings are immutable

Per 1. you cannot replace an element while iterating the container, and per 2. you cannot mutate the contained object.

That means that you will have to build a new container and replace the container as a whole. The Pythonic way would be to use a set comprehension as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40231770/3545273) to the linked question, or by using [@Thy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70956251/3545273)

Answer (score 2):

Update:
@user2357112 supports Monica found an example which verifies that modifying a set during iteration is still unsafe in Python 3. In that case, the easiest thing to do is to build a new set.

```
new_unique = {k[2:] if k.startswith('A_') else k for k in unique_names}
```

If you need to update the set in place (say, you are updating a set passed as a parameter), you may as well just clear the set and update it with the new one. For example,

```
def update_set(s):
    new_unique = {k[2:] if k.startswith('A_') else k for k in s}
    s.clear()
    s.update(new_unique)

update_set(unique_names)
```

---

Since strings are immutable, you have to remove the old string and add its replacement to the original set. You can try

```
for x in unique_names:
    if x.startswith('A_'):
        unique_names.add(x[2:])
        unique_names.remove(x)
```

In Python 2, you would get a `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`. That doesn't appear to be the case in Python 3, or at least in Python 3.9. I'm not entirely convinced that this is guaranteed to be correct, though.

Comment: You could use `for x in list(unique_names)` to avoid the headache of removing from the collection you are iterating over. Builds a temporary list of course, don't know if OP allows that.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be correct. You can still end up triggering a hash table rebuild and completely rearranging the hash table layout, breaking the iteration. You'll also see nondeterministic results for whether anything you add during the loop gets picked up by the loop - if the set starts with an element `'A_A_whatever'`, you can't tell whether the final result will be `'A_whatever'` or `'whatever'`.

Comment: It took a lot of runs, but I eventually managed to get a run where the hash randomization and collision resolution worked out so one of the input elements got skipped: https://ideone.com/dIaOEQ

Comment: (Note that taking a lot of runs to see the bug is a *bad* thing - it means bugs like this are very hard to reproduce, isolate, and debug.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks a lot for your comments, I almost accepted this answer because the code was very "readable". Did not realize it was not safe...

Comment: Yes, thanks for confirming this is not correct. I though perhaps the fact that Python was no longer raising a `RuntimeError` means something about `set_iterator` had changed to avoid the issue.

Comment: Regarding the nondeterminism, I don't think that's an issue. Every element (when processed correctly) simply has at most one `A_` prefix removed. While that can change the size of the resulting set (`{'A_foo', 'foo'}` becomes `{'foo'}`), it's still deterministic.

Comment: [Here's a run where two `A_` prefixes get removed.](https://ideone.com/c4yaTa)